# How to return JSON from a ASP.NET Core Web API, such that it's displayed properly formatted in the browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, .net-core

I want to return JSON from my ASP.NET Core Web API, such that it's displayed structurally in the browser and not as a quoted string:

```
"{\"Url\":null,\"Entry\":null,\"Type\":0,\"Priority\":false}"
```

To achieve this, I've mapped the `.json` extension to the `application/json` MIME type, such that the path `/api/zap.json` returns a JSON response:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml"));
    options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("json", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
})
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

The web API (GET) returns its ZapScan parameter as a JSON string, so I've set the return type to `ActionResult<string>`:

```
// GET: api/zap.{format}
// https://localhost:5001/api/zap?url=https://example.com&entry=/&type=active&priority=true
[HttpGet, FormatFilter]
public ActionResult<string> OnGet([FromQuery] ZapScan scan)
{
    _zapDispatcher.Dispatch(scan);
    return ToJson(scan);
}

private string ToJson<T>(T obj)
{
    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
}
```

**ZapScan:**

```
public class ZapScan
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Entry { get; set; }
    public ScanType Type { get; set; }
    public bool Priority { get; set; }
}
```

I've verified that the web API properly sets the HTTP `Content-Type` header to `application/json` to inform the browser that its response is JSON formatted:

[image]

How can make the browser display my JSON structurally? - e.g:

```
{
    "url": "null",
    "entry": "null",
    "type": 0,
    "priority": false
}
```

Comment: So then what you want to return is formatted `text/html`? Otherwise it's up to the browser to display the JSON however that's done in the browser.

Comment: @JLe - my browser properly displays JSON as structured output for e.g: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Comment: You are mixing up data plus its presentation. You should avoid doing this in the API. If this is for your own purpose (E.g. Just to validate the returned data in the browser), you should use some browser plugins to do this job.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't return a string from your method, because then the browser will show that as a string (of course). Instead, return the `scan` object as actual json using the [Ok helper method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

```
[HttpGet, FormatFilter]
public ActionResult OnGet([FromQuery] ZapScan scan)
{
    _zapDispatcher.Dispatch(scan);
    return Ok(scan);
}
```

Comment: how does ASP.NET Core knows that it should convert `ZapScan` to JSON and not XML or something similar? Also, do you know why XML output formatter removes `null` properties in the response?

Comment: Based on the header in the request, or otherwise you can force it.

Comment: but what if the client sends an `Accept */*` header - then ASP.NET has multiple options for choosing the content-type of the response?

Comment: Then it would be JSON as that's the default in Web Api.

Answer (score 2):

First of all,

`return Ok(scan)` would return `string` without `content-type`

So you could try:

`return Content(scan, "application/json")` which will set your `content-type`
to **application-json**,

But still on the browser, it will display as if it is like a **string**, so you can download (If you are using **Chrome**) `JsonFormatter` from this link:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=tr

**EDIT**

```
var json = ToJson(scan);
return Content(json, "application/json");
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to serialise the object to json. You can directly use the following:

```
// GET: api/zap.{format}
// https://localhost:5001/api/zap? 
url=https://example.com&entry=/&type=active&priority=true
[HttpGet, FormatFilter]
public ActionResult<string> OnGet([FromQuery] ZapScan scan)
{
   _zapDispatcher.Dispatch(scan);
    return OK(scan);
}
```

This also works for anonymous objects.

You can also use:

```
// GET: api/zap.{format}
// https://localhost:5001/api/zap? 
url=https://example.com&entry=/&type=active&priority=true
[HttpGet, FormatFilter]
public ActionResult<string> OnGet([FromQuery] ZapScan scan)
{
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

_zapDispatcher.Dispatch(scan);
response.Content = new StringContent(scan, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that using AddMvc() with options is the way to configure returning JSON in Net Core MVC Controllers.

However, the main problem is that the JsonOption objects are not configured correctly.

```
   services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
                options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        })
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
            });
```

This should be enough to return correctly formatted JSON.

**Alternate method**

An alternative is to create your own Controller and add your own custom JsonResult methods to map correctly.

See this link for [a gist](https://gist.github.com/jpoehls/1424538)